# Is there an R library for drawing polygons and than generating RGB array?

Tags: r

I'm trying to generate array of RGB values for an image which contains n polygons I've added. Each polygon is defined with n points, fill color and opacity. Polygons can overlap.
**My goal isn't to plot the image, just to get an RGB array representing it**

Currently I'm using Imager package, but it only allows me to draw rectangles. I've also looked at raster package, but it seems to be no help. Implot could be useful, but I cannot find support for polygons.

Using imager, currently I have following code:

```r
cimg(array(1, c(width,height,1,3))) -> img1

draw_rect(img, x0, y0, x1, y1, opacity = 1, color="BLACK",filled = TRUE) -> img1
```

where img1 object contains RGB array

**Problem solved:**

Another example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

eg. when I'm trying to get an RGB array of an image containing polygons defined with points (10,10), (20,20), (30,10), (20, 50), and two others just moved along the x axis by 10 and 20 offset:

```r
width <- height <- 250

xes <- c(10,20,30,20)
yes <- c(10,20,10,50)
cimg(array(1, c(width,height,1,3))) -> img3

img3 %>% 
  implot(., polygon(xes, yes, col = rgb(red = 0, green = 0, blue = 1, alpha = 0.5), border=NA),
       rescale = FALSE ) %>% 
  implot(.,polygon(xes+ 10, yes, col = rgb(red = 1, green = 0, blue = 0, alpha = 0.5), border=NA),
       rescale = FALSE ) %>%
  implot(.,polygon(xes+ 20, yes, col = rgb(red = 0, green = 1, blue = 0, alpha = 0.5), border=NA),
       rescale = FALSE ) -> out

out[,,1,] #prints out RGB array which I need
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide the data you're using?  it's pretty tricky to help without having sample data to try with.

Comment: In any case take a look at `ggplot2`'s [`geom_polygon`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_polygon.html)

Comment: @DS_UNI It's not a data analysis problem. I'm trying to reproduce Mona Lisa evolution (https://rogerjohansson.blog/2008/12/07/genetic-programming-evolution-of-mona-lisa/) using GA library in R. 

Even thought I've solved the problem, my next question is "Is this the fastest it can be?" Because I'm doing a lot of those computations, and it's really effecting performance.